# Workflow - Moving Actions Up/Down

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a step in which 5 actions run in parallel. It's a Collect data from... task. If at any time I need to go into the workflow to make changes to this step (add action somewhere in the middle, move up or down) SPD wont oblige. It adds actions to the bottom. Can't move them at all (up/down).

I tried switching back to run in sequence, but still can't move actions. Tried adding a step and moving it. Nothing. Move existing? Nada.

Anyone else see this before??? Solutions?

SP2007
SPD 2007

Answer (score 1):

You cant move action, only delete and recreate it in enother place.

Answer (score -1):

First select Run All actions in parallel, 
Add parameter / whatever you want to do..
and then switch back again to Run All actions in SEQUENCE.